# R: How to rename a list's name?

Tags: r, list, rename

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997377/how-to-rename-elements-list-indexed-by-a-loop-in-r), the top answer gives a solution to change the element of the list. I am wondering if there is a way to rename the list's "names" after they have already been defined. As a small example:

```
> a <- list(1, 2, 3)
> names(a) <- c('A','B',"C")

> a
$A
[1] 1

$B
[1] 2

$C
[1] 3

> names(a[1]) <- 'D' #does not work
> a
$A
[1] "test1"

$B
[1] "test2"

$C
[1] "test3"
```

How can I rename the `names` here?

Comment: `names(a)[1] = "D"` **OR** `names(a) = gsub("A", "D", names(a))`

Comment: Figured it was something silly like this...thanks @d.b